# Getting RuntimeException for kotlin code

Tags: kotlin

I am using Bluetooth LE for fetching surrounding devices but I am not getting a **list** and also I am getting **Runtime Exception** here is stack-trace

```
06-18 13:59:33.188 10189-10189/com.labs.aress.bleomronkotlin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.labs.aress.bleomronkotlin, PID: 10189
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.labs.aress.bleomronkotlin/com.labs.aress.bleomronkotlin.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
    at com.labs.aress.bleomronkotlin.BaseMainActivity.onActivityResult(BaseMainActivity.kt)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

code is here

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        AppLog.dMethodIn()
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (REQUEST_CODE_SCAN != requestCode) {
            AppLog.w("Unknown request code : $requestCode")
            return
        }
        if (BleScanActivity.RESPONSE_CODE_CONNECT != resultCode) {
            return
        }

        val discoverPeripheral = data.getParcelableExtra<DiscoverPeripheral?>(BleScanActivity.EXTRA_CONNECT_REQUEST_PERIPHERAL)
        if (null == discoverPeripheral) {
            AppLog.e("null == discoverPeripheral")
            return
        }

        initDeviceInfoView()
        initConnectionView()

        onConnect(discoverPeripheral)
    }
```

I dont understand why data is throwing null

Comment: Have you tried to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Those have helped me in the past when debugging such type of problems.

Comment: try changing the param to `data: Intent?` instead of `data:Intent` and do watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uizh2WlJtnk at around 25 mins

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the data parameter is not nullable, but Android calls it with a null value.

If you override the onActivityResult function in Android Studio the function signature you get is actually

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

as opposed to what you have

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent)
```

The difference is the ? after the "data: Intent"
Add the ? and make the appropriate changes to your code (to account for the nullable value) and it should work.